# How to use reflection to access private fields with constructor injection?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, reflection

How to use reflection to access the networkUtil Field? I want to access the private field networkUtil field in my test class

```
class AbcViewModel constructor(app: Application) : BaseViewModel(app) {

 companion object {
    private const val TAG = "AbcViewModel"
 }

 private val networkUtil = NetworkUtil(app)
 ....

}
```

Comment: It is usually not advised to have classes creating their own internal instances. Better to use dependency injection and "inject" them. 
So in your scenario you could instead have: `class AbcViewModel constructor(private val networkUtil: NetworkUtil) : BaseViewModel(app) {` So in your test you can pass a mocked `NetworkUtil` to do your tests

Comment: @Eselfar If this is already implemented, Is there any way to mock this for unit tests?

Comment: Yes. If you use [Mockk](https://mockk.io/) you can say the `NetworkUtil` is a `mockk` and initialise you system under test (the `AbcViewModel)` with it.
Then you can mock any behaviour of the `NetworkUtil` even if the `NetworkUtil` is a class.